# generar reporte pdf desde un json file en python

Tags: python, json, pdf

estoy trantando de hacer un reporte generado desde un archivo json en python.
Mi projecto es generar varios tipos de reportes y estoy investigando como hacerlo con pdf... tengo un reporte grafico con pandas que también me gustaria incluir en el pdf a futuro, pero lo que mas me interesa ahora es poder desde la lectura del archivo json crear un reporte que contenga tal vez en una tabla o algo prolijo los datos que tengo en el json file
este es mi json

```
{
  "services": [
    {
      "name": "ac",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "running",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "42%"
    },
    {
      "name": "acc",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "running",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "63%"
    },
    {
      "name": "acv",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "running",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "47%"
    },
    {
      "name": "acf",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "running",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "48%"
    },
    {
      "name": "ach",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "error",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "10%"
    },
    {
      "name": "acj",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "stopped",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "43%"
    },
    {
      "name": "acq",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "running",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "65%"
    },
    {
      "name": "bc",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "stopped",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "20%"
    },
        {
      "name": "bcc",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "running",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "25%"
    },
    {
      "name": "bcx",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "error",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "14%"
    },
    {
      "name": "bcn",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "running",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "45%"
    },
    {
      "name": "bcm",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "stopped",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "35%"
    }
  ]
}
```

y lo que quiero hacer por ejemplo es que en una tabla me genere estos datos ordenados como para presentar en un reporte justamente y bueno después agregarle por ejemplo otros datos como un titulo autor, numero de paginas y damas.
es posible?

Answer (score 0):

deberias usar pdfwriter y usar json.loads(tujson) ejemplo :

```
data = json.loads(tujson)
nombre = data["name"]
#asi con todos los atributos
```

y con pdfwriter solo es el setear todo los atributos que necesitas aqui puedes ver los atributos [here](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PdfFileWriter.html)

Comment: yo lo tengo definido así :
`def get_data():
    with open('services.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        return data`
así esta bien? o tengo que ir por todos los datos? como por ejemplo
`
nombre = data["name"]
service =data["service"]
`
etc, lei la documentación no me queda claro como hacerlo, pero voy a usar reportlab en este caso seria similar?